# How to add Javascript file into html Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

i want to use Javascript file in my Django project. But somehow I can't figure out how to import it into my html file. I tried to add it same way as I did my css file but it doesn't work. On load it shows always the same error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: fun1 is not defined at onload".

Project structure:

[image: ![projectStructure]

Js file, coding.js:
`function fun1(){ alert("It works!") }`

Html file, index.html:
`<script src="{% static '/js/coding.js' %}"></script>`

and as I mentioned, the css file, the line above, works just fine:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>`

Adding `type: text/javascript` doesn't fix it.

Comment: take a closer look ... you did not specify the js file the same way as the css file

Comment: There is a difference between `css/style.css` and `/css/style.css`

Comment: fixed the "/", but it does't solve the problem. Still the same error message

Comment: inspect the website and check if what is actually being imported on the src tag is available to be imported.

I think this goes more on the side of collectingstatics or setting up the static folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Somehow the .js file is not loaded when calling the function in `<body onload="function()">`

I wrote the function in html tag `<script>` and it's working fine.

However if I call different function in different part of html like in select onchange it normally takes it from the .js file

Thanks for help.